# Change the links in Ask Ubuntu contact page

Tags: bug, status-completed, https

There are two links in [Ask Ubuntu contact page](https://askubuntu.com/contact).

[image: Screenshot of links in https://askubuntu.com/contact]

- The first one is for contacting Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us (HTTP )

  This redirects to https://ubuntu.com/contact-us. I feel the link can be changed to https://ubuntu.com/contact-us.
- The second one is for contacting Canonical: http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us (HTTP )

  This redirects to https://ubuntu.com/support/contact-us. I feel that the redirected site is a bit irrelevant to contacting Canonical. I feel the link needs to be changed to this: https://canonical.com/contact-us

Comment: If the link already redirects to https://ubuntu.com/contact-us, is there any reason to change it? Also, why do we need to care about ways of contacting Canonical? We're not Canonical, we don't work for them, we're just volunteers. If they want some other link there, then they can contact SE and deal with it. Is this really something relevant to the AU community?

Comment: @terdon Both the links are HTTP links; at least they can be changed to HTTPS links. At the end of the day, the contact links exist in **our** contact page, so we must care about it. IMO, your comment talks about the purpose of having the contact links. I suggest you to create a separate meta post proposing to remove the contact links if you feel they are unnecessary.

Comment: Tagging this for review because at minimum we should be sending by secure links. These were probably missed because I don't think anyone realized Ask Ubuntu had custom links set there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've removed the second link (to Canonical) and updated the link to Ubuntu so that it doesn't redirect. I've also added a link to the Ubuntu Launchpad site with information about using it for bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Can you please add the Launchpad logo such that the contact page will look nice?

Comment: I looked for one that was the right size and couldn't find one - at least not easily. If you have one, I can add it, sure.

Comment: Catija, I hope this will be helpful: https://launchpad.net/@@/launchpad-logo.png

Comment: Catija, can you please look into the links in the [meta contact page](https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact)? The Ubuntu and Google contact links are HTTP. Also, the Yahoo, Google and Ubuntu links redirect to different sites now. Please update them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Catija.

Answer (score 5):

Both links should be removed.

To me, they look like legacy stubs that never really took off and have outlived their usefulness.

Neither provides a useful way to communicate with the Ubuntu Project.

- Ubuntu Contact leads to https://ubuntu.com/contact-us
  ...which, in turn, has a 'technical support' link leading to https://ubuntu.com/support/contact-us
  (The page sells Ubuntu Advantage. It's not a support page)
  ...which, in turn has a 'Need Help?' section with a link right back to AskUBuntu.
- Contact Canonical leads directly to the same sales page for Ubuntu Advantage.

The most effective way for users to communicate with the Ubuntu Project is generally for the user to ask a question about their specific problem on AskUbuntu.

AskUbuntu should not be funneling lost querants to a sales page. It's (not intentionally) misleading and seems disingenuous to new and lost users.

Answer (score 3):

The two links lead to the same information, so I guess at most we can include one of them https://ubuntu.com/contact-us

I tend to agree with [user535733's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19709/527764) suggesting that we don't need these links at all. The contact page is very sales oriented, sadly.

Thinking about what might actually help people, maybe we could add a link to https://launchpad.net/. Launchpad is the development platform for Ubuntu, where bug reports and feature requests should be posted (instead of on Ask Ubuntu!)

And/or we could add a link to the discourse homepage https://discourse.ubuntu.com/

Also, what about adding contact pages for flavors? These are much more useful than the page at ubuntu.com:

- https://xubuntu.org/contact/
- https://discourse.lubuntu.me/
- https://kubuntu.org/support/
- https://ubuntu-mate.org/support/
- https://ubuntukylin.com
- https://ubuntustudio.org/support/
- https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/

Comment: How about one link to a page that shows links to all those flavours, so it doesn't take up a lot of space?

Comment: I don't know of a page that has all these links, other than this meta post...

Comment: What about providing a link to an answer or question that only provides these links? When we click on an image on a page we only see the picture, I don't know of anything similar where you can post links rather than images?

Comment: @Zanna I _suggest_ you to propose this as a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @RandomPerson I was asked by Catija to post my ideas as an answer to your question